# What page handles products? WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress

I wanted to know which page PHP handles the products in the WooCommerce plugin. 
I would like to make changes to the button "buy" option on the product page, but I can not figure out which page is responsible for doing this. 
Who can help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to edit the product listing page you have to look for `content-product.php` and if you want to edit single product page you have to look for `content-single-product.php` in the `templates` folder of woo-commerce plugin folder.